# How to calculate risk contribution of assets in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to write a block of code that will allow me to identify the risk contribution of assets in a portfolio. The covariance matrix is a 6x6 pandas dataframe.

My code is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

weights = np.array([.1,.2,.05,.25,.1,.3]) 

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,6),columns = 'a','b','c','d','e','f'])
covariance = data.cov()

portfolio_variance = (weights*covariance*weights.T)[0,0]
sigma = np.sqrt(portfolio_variance)
marginal_risk = covariance*weights.T
risk_contribution = np.multiply(marginal_risk, weights.T)/sigma
print(risk_contribution)
```

When I try to run the code I get a KeyError, and if I remove the `[0,0]` from `portfolio_variance` I get output that doesn't seem to make sense.

Can somebody point me to my error(s)?

Comment: Can you please include a runnable expression for the `covariance` dataframe?  That is really the critical part.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: As @NicholasM noted, your code will cause a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on `covariance = 6x6 dataframe`. It would help if your code was a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including any `import` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Three problems with your code:

Open your list operator square brackets on line 6:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,6),columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

You're using the two dimensional indexing operator wrong. You can't say `[0,0]`, you have to say `[0][0]`.

And last, because you named the columns, you have to use them when indexing, so it's actually `['a'][0]`:

```py
portfolio_variance = (weights*covariance*weights.T)['a'][0]
```

Final working code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

weights = np.array([.1,.2,.05,.25,.1,.3]) 

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,6),columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
covariance = data.cov()

portfolio_variance = (weights*covariance*weights.T)['a'][0]
sigma = np.sqrt(portfolio_variance)
marginal_risk = covariance*weights.T
risk_contribution = np.multiply(marginal_risk, weights.T)/sigma
print(risk_contribution)
```

Comment: @IronMarshal did this solution work for you? If so, can you accept the answer? If not, what's still the matter? Maybe we can still get an answer that works.

Answer (score 2):

```
portfolio_variance =(weights*covariance*weights.T)
```

portfolio_variance should be

```
portfolio_variance =(weights@covariance@weights.T)
```

This will provide the portfolio variance, which should be a single number.

same for marginal risk, it should be

```
marginal_risk = covariance@weights.T
```